# Maximum size allowed for app_data

Tags: c#, asp.net

Is there maximum size allowed for the use of app_data folder in asp.net projects? if yes, can somebody please tell me the exact capacity of it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no such limit on  app_data folder. All depends on where you deployed and amount of free memory you have in deployment location.

If there is OS disk quota which link to the user who running asp.net application, that limit will apply.

Comment: Thanks for answering pal, do you have specific reference for this?